# Windows 10: Controlling Where the Reserved Partition is Created

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, windows-installation, system-reserved-partition

I have 2 drives:

- 2 TB OS
- 2 TB Data

To my understanding what I need to do, is to create a 2 TB partition for the entire Data drive, create a 1 TB partition for the OS drive, and then Windows installation will be forced to make the reserved partition in the only available free space, which is the OS drive?

Do I need to make room at the start of the OS drive -- does the reserved partition always have to be at that location? which tool to use?

Comment: You need to account for the the ESP at the beginning of the drive if your PC is UEFI.

Comment: This doen't answer your question, but may be of some use. I know I made the system partitions manually when installing my multiboot system. Windows complained when installing, and still complains about 'a non-recommended order of partitions', but it still works, even if I also created the partitions much larger than recommended (it's still just MBs, not GBs) to allow for 'future expansions'.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to let Windows allocate its own partitions.

- Ensure in the BIOS that the OS disk is shown as the first disk
- I would prefer to disconnect the Data disk to avoid complications
- Install Windows to the disk and specify new partition size (512 GB is already a lot),
  or select a partition if already allocated.
  Ensure unallocated space exists for Windows to allocate a Restore partition of the right
  size.
  Do not delete by mistake your manufacturer's recovery partitions.
- Reconnect the Data disk.